# Error al usar 'INSERT INTO table SET ?' con el módulo mysql2 para Node.js

Tags: mysql, nodejs

Tengo varias consultas SQL que al momento de insertar una fila requiere varios campos, y quiero que en vez de usar `INSERT INTO table (campos...) VALUES (valores...)` pueda usar `INSERT INTO table SET ?`, y así, no especificar todos los campos con sus valores.

Mi código de ejemplo es este:

```
async function insert(body){
    try {
        const {title, description} = body;
        const query = 'INSERT INTO tasks (title, description) VALUES (?, ?)';
        
        return await connection.execute(query, [title, description]);
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
}
```

Este código devuelve un error:

```
async function insert(body){
    try {
        const query = 'INSERT INTO tasks SET ?';
        
        return await connection.execute(query, [body]);
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
}
```

El error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

Este código me permitiría hacer una función genérica para cualquier tabla de la base de datos, ya que la variable `query` puede pasarse como parámetro, quedando de esta forma:

```
async function insert(query, body){
    try {
        return await connection.execute(query, [body]);
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
}
```